# Where does update-secureboot-policy save the keys?

Tags: secure-boot

I need to sign the kernel modules for virtualbox but I can't find the keys that were created when I ran `update-secureboot-policy --new-key`. Does anyone know where this is saved?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. So I used
`sudo find / -type f -name '*MOK*'`
Keys were found in `/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/*`
Then I rebuild drivers and execute command
`sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der $(modinfo -n vmmon)` to sign new module
In your case probably you have another module name (not vmmon)
Do not forget restart VM service via init or systemd depending on your platform

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor variation of the answer above:

```
$ sudo updatedb # To ensure the index is fresh
$ sudo locate MOK
/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
```